# AJAX Jquery url not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a strange problem with Jquery Ajax with the following code.

**Situation 1:**

```
function leuk(decrease_id, user_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://schoolprove.nl/nieuw/index.php/leerlingen/checkvoortgang/',
        data: 'decrease_id=' + decrease_id + '&user_id=' + user_id,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#output').html(msg);

        }
    });
}
```

**Situation 2**

```
function leuk(decrease_id, user_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/nieuw/index.php/leerlingen/checkvoortgang/',
        data: 'decrease_id=' + decrease_id + '&user_id=' + user_id,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#output').html(msg);

        }
    });
}
```

The AJAX url works sometimes whith http:// and sometimes without. I build and error catch when a error occured. This works very well at IE but Firefox doesn't give a error. So at some computers with Firefox this will not work. It is very strange and i don't know why it will not work.

Situation 1: Works sometimes

Situation 2: Works sometimes

Sometimes situation 1 works and ad a other computer situation 2 works, WHY?
Anybody know how to solve?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you mean when you include the full url with `http://` it does not work? Because this will be cause by browser security. You can not perform AJAX cross domain therefor you have to use a relative path such as `/something`, `./something` or `../something`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions it is causing due to cache, try to disable the cache and add the random value in your query string.

```
function leuk(decrease_id,user_id)
              {     
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    cache:fale,
                    timeout:10000,
                    url: '/nieuw/index.php/leerlingen/checkvoortgang/?rnd='+Math.random(),

                    data: 'decrease_id='+decrease_id+'&user_id='+user_id,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#output').html(msg);

                }
                });
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirect your domain like this tonerize.com to www.tonerize.com will solve this issue

please read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. for more information

Answer (score 1):

Is your ajax file located on some other server?

If no then, you need not specify the the whole path for url.
Its enough if you use

url: 'ajaxfilename.php' //depending on the folder the file is located

Comment: Thanks for your your help! The file located on the same server.When i use http://website/filename it works, but on a other computer it doesn't work and then i have to use /filename. So when i use http:// It works, but on a other computer it will work without http://. i can not use one if them. I like t know why that changes on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a path such as this for AJAX.

```
http://something.com/file.php
```

It has to be relative to your file and located on your server like to.

```
/file.php
```

I am not quite sure what your problem is though, your question does not provide any error information.

Comment: Thanks for your your help! The file located on the same server.When i use website/filename it works, but on a other computer it doesn't work and then i have to use /filename. So when i use http:// It works, but on a other computer it will work without http://. i can not use one if them. I like t know why that changes on different computers.

Comment: Are the computers running different operating systems or browsers?